# Binding Library Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, eclipse, xamarin.android, mjpeg

I want to build an application with monodroid to have a live video stream from an IPCamera (with MJpeg format) to my tablet. after digging the internet I found that there is a Mjpeg Library project written in Java from [here](http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/1484). it has two files `MjpegView.java` and `MjpegInputStream.Java` which I put them both here:

*MjpegView.java*

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

    public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1; 
    public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
    public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

    private MjpegViewThread thread;
    private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;    
    private boolean showFps = false;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private boolean surfaceDone = false;    
    private Paint overlayPaint;
    private int overlayTextColor;
    private int overlayBackgroundColor;
    private int ovlPos;
    private int dispWidth;
    private int dispHeight;
    private int displayMode;

    public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private int frameCounter = 0;
        private long start;
        private Bitmap ovl;

        public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

        private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
            int tempx;
            int tempy;
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
                float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
                bmw = dispWidth;
                bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
                if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                    bmh = dispHeight;
                    bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
                }
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
            return null;
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
            synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
                dispWidth = width;
                dispHeight = height;
            }
        }

        private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
            Rect b = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
            int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
            int bheight = b.height()+2;
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
            p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
            c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
            return bm;           
        }

        public void run() {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
            Bitmap bm;
            int width;
            int height;
            Rect destRect;
            Canvas c = null;
            Paint p = new Paint();
            String fps = "";
            while (mRun) {
                if(surfaceDone) {
                    try {
                        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                            try {
                                bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                if(showFps) {
                                    p.setXfermode(mode);
                                    if(ovl != null) {
                                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                        width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                    }
                                    p.setXfermode(null);
                                    frameCounter++;
                                    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                        frameCounter = 0; 
                                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {}
                        }
                    } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
        overlayPaint = new Paint();
        overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
        overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
        overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
        displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
        dispWidth = getWidth();
        dispHeight = getHeight();
    }

    public void startPlayback() { 
        if(mIn != null) {
            mRun = true;
            thread.start();         
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayback() { 
        mRun = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
        surfaceDone = false; 
        stopPlayback(); 
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context) { super(context); init(context); }    
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { surfaceDone = true; }
    public void showFps(boolean b) { showFps = b; }
    public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) { mIn = source; startPlayback();}
    public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) { overlayPaint = p; }
    public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) { overlayTextColor = c; }
    public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) { overlayBackgroundColor = c; }
    public void setOverlayPosition(int p) { ovlPos = p; }
    public void setDisplayMode(int s) { displayMode = s; }
}
```

*MjpegInputStream.Java*

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
    private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
    private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
    private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
    private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
    private int mContentLength = -1;

    public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
        HttpResponse res;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

    private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
        int seqIndex = 0;
        byte c;
        for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
            c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
            if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
                seqIndex++;
                if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
            } else seqIndex = 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
        int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
        return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
    }

    private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
        ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(headerIn);
        return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
    }   

    public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
        mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
        reset();
        byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
        readFully(header);
        try {
            mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
            mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
        }
        reset();
        byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
        skipBytes(headerLen);
        readFully(frameData);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
    }
}
```

so I converted that (actually create a c# wrapper) with [Binding Library](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29) project.

but although I followed the Sample code tutorial of this project as following:

**The sample itself:**

```
public class MjpegSample extends Activity {
    private MjpegView mv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //sample public cam
        String URL = "http://webcam5.hrz.tu-darmstadt.de/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240"; 

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mv = new MjpegView(this);
        setContentView(mv);        

        mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(true);
    }
```

**What I have Done in Monodroid:**

```
namespace AndroidApplication8
{
    [Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication8", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            String URL = "rtsp://192.168.1.3/Mjpeg/video.cgi";
            var mv = new MjpegView(this);
            SetContentView(mv);
            **mv.SetSource(MjpegInputStream.Read(URL));
            mv.SetDisplayMode(MjpegView.SizeBestFit);
            mv.StartPlayback();
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me an error in the line indicated with ** when it wants to execute `MjpegInputStream.Read()`

and it jumps to the class converted from the native Java files without any more information.

[image]

Comment: do you get any further error information in VS or through LogCat? Did you try to use FullScreen as well as in the example?

Comment: What error? If you try to catch an exception, do you get anything?

Comment: Could you please tape the url "rtsp://192.168.1.3/Mjpeg/video.cgi" on android browser and tell us if the streaming is working ? otherwise you have to check your video type.

Comment: @Anis Yes it is working there dude

Answer (score 1):

You should check your video type.For example if your video encoding is compressed over there(before getting to your android device) you should encode it before put it into your browser.This could let you write a code in java for example to verify the incoming stream from cameras first(don't use build-in browser of android) and then decode it manually.
Good luck!